# static polymorphism elements inside vector

Tags: c++, vector, variant, crtp

i'm trying to create vector of variant

1)I have two crtp classes, for example

```
template<class D>
struct DrawableItem;
struct box : DrawableItem<box>
struct icosahedron : DrawableItem<icosahedron>
```

then i process them like this:

```
box b;
icosahedron g;
using types = std::variant<icosahedron*,box*>;
std::vector<types> itemVec{ &b,&g};
for (auto& e : itemVec)
{
 std::visit([&vec = this->allItems](auto& e) {
     for (auto& x : e->riVec)
         vec.push_back(&x);
     }, e);
}
```

works fine, but if something wrong here explain it please.

2)now i'm trying to use std::variant to hold my types directly. As long as i know all my types i want to have struct with one vector for each type that i have and push elements into this somehow.
i do not manage even create this structure. The following code doesnt compile, just idea

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template<typename... args>
struct tete
{
    using allTypes=std::variant<args...>;
    using innerVec=std::vector<allTypes>;
    std::vector<innerVec> generalVec;
    tete()
    {
        if constexpr(sizeof...(args) == 0)return;
        createVec<args...>();
    }
    template<typename X, typename... rest>
    void createVec()
    {
        
        {
            generalVec.push_back(std::vector<X>{});
        }
        createVec<rest...>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    tete<int, float>();
}
```

Gives the error:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'void tete<args>::createVec() [with X = int; rest = {float}; args = {int, float}]':
<source>:13:27:   required from 'tete<args>::tete() [with args = {int, float}]'
<source>:28:22:   required from here
<source>:20:33: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > > > >::push_back(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)'
   20 |             generalVec.push_back(std::vector<X>{});
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/vector:66,
                 from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1278:7: note: candidate: 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > > >; value_type = std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > >]'
 1278 |       push_back(const value_type& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1278:35: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' to 'const std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > > > >::value_type&' {aka 'const std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > >&'}
 1278 |       push_back(const value_type& __x)
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1295:7: note: candidate: 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > > >; value_type = std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > >]'
 1295 |       push_back(value_type&& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:1295:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' to 'std::vector<std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > > > >::value_type&&' {aka 'std::vector<std::variant<int, float>, std::allocator<std::variant<int, float> > >&&'}
 1295 |       push_back(value_type&& __x)
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

How can i do this if it's possible?

Comment: Most of the compilers I use would complain at `void main()`. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Your two examples are a bit conflicting.  Do you want a `std::vector` that holds all of your objects (via `std::variant` objects) or do you want individual vectors for each type?  The latter likely doesn't need `std::variant` at all, just a `std::tuple<std::vector<args>...>`: [example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99e52c7e52add0ca).

Comment: @TedLyngmo assuming you're compiling with warnings on. Which would be opt _out_ if the world made any kind of sense...

Comment: @Chris I tried it without warning flags in gcc, clang, icx and MSVC. Only MSVC accepts it.  :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am pleasantly surprised.

Comment: `generalVec` is declared to hold a vector of variants. You are trying to add a vector of ints to it; this is the immediate cause of the error. Like others, I don't understand what you are trying to do. Your original example had a vector of variants. The wording of part 2 talks about "one vector for each type". How does `vector<vector<variant>>` fit into this picture?

Comment: @MilesBudnek thank you. Tuple is what i m looking for probably. Is there a way to pass allocator for vector in your example?

Comment: `std::vector` accepts an allocator type as its second template parameter, so you could pass that fairly easily.  If you need something more specific than that I would recommend asking it as a new question.